# Como puedo crear una columna que separe datos de otra misma

Tags: powerbi, dax

Tengo una Columna tipo Text que contiene datos tanto numericos, decimales, fechas y texto, lo que quiero es una funcion que me separe las que son texto y las que son texto y las que son numero, tengo esta formula, pero dejo de funcionar en Direct query y no me da la opcion de permisos :/

```
IsText = IF(ISERROR(VALUE('Table_name'[Valor_columna])),"Text","Number")
```

el error que me marca es "Function 'ISERROR' is not allowed as part of calculated column DAX expressions on DirectQuery models." pero no encuentro una funcion permitida en direct query que me de el resultado